Is there a way to create a connector not an app on akeneo?
Is it possible to create not an app but a simple connector that installs as an extension on Akeneo PIM to invoke an external printing service, for instance? If so, how?
I have tried to create an app, but it doesn't fit what I'm looking for because I would need to completely recreate a user interface, whereas I already have an existing UI that I simply want to connect

If you using community edition you can add a connector that does what you need and customize its options thought the Export profile.
On the profile you allow changing the endpoint, add print options, etc..
You need to create a bundle for that and there are examples on Akeneo Docs. have you seen their documentation? https://docs.akeneo.com/5.0/import_and_export_data/guides/clean-csv-file-during-product-import.html#create-the-connector
That should be easy if you are good symfony experience otherwise I would recommend you to get an expert since that may be challenging.
